# 18.04 not booting after editing GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT

Tags: boot, grub2

Clean install of 18.04 I have a R9 390X and FX 6350 cpu. Trying to follow this advice by u/toidiboy: [in this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/wine_gaming/comments/8u2hys/cant_get_winedxvk_working_to_run_elder_scrolls/e1dc82i/)

Edited /etc/default/grub by adding:

```
radeon.si_support=0 radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.cik_support=1"
```

It is otherwise the default with only:

```
"quiet splash
```

at the beginning.

Save it then run sudo apt-get update.Reboot and it won't load. I don't remember what DID show but I can't reproduce without breaking my current install again.

TLDR: How can I repair my grub parameters when I break it like this? Can I boot from livedisk and edit that grub commandline that's in my installed Ubuntu?

Comment: If you can get to the grub menu, you should be able to edit the line by pressing `e`

Comment: @steeldriver Is this through the live disk or in the bootup of the installed Ubuntu instance? For either of these, I'm unsure of how to get to the file to edit that GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line

Comment: From the installed instance - I'm just suggesting editing the line in the grub menu so that you can boot successfully. After that, edit the file the same way you did before.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance on this, but how do I get to this grub menu? I assume it's something during bootup? (since I wouldn't be able to access it from within the instance since it won't boot up all the way).

Comment: It should be possible by hitting SHIFT during boot - but it can be tricky to get the timing right. See for example [How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time)

Comment: @steeldriver got it. Thanks! Turns out the grub edit wasn't the problem... I installed some stuff from the padoka ppa and I think it's causing issues. But this thread is solved. Thanks!